# Make wordard in vb6

Tags: vba, vb6

How would I be able to make a program like words WORDART that has 3d text and text effects? Would I need pictures for each letter with the cool effects of is there a different way to to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems like a good idea to have pictures for each letter or number but that's a lot of pictures for capital letters and regular letters, you also would have to load each file which can take some time, so it doesn't sound so practical to do. A better option would be to make a user control that makes a picture at run time with the word art in it wand has the cool effects, a example is here
http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=70216&lngWId=1
aanother example is at http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/word-powerpoint-outlook-and-other-office-products/101964-import-ms-word-art-object-visual-basic.html

Comment: I'd imagine there is a api that allows you to change the border color for the font and the other colors of the text.

Comment: Not to mention there are ~80,000 CJK characters defined in unicode, thats even more images.

Comment: Any idea how office does it? Even if they don't use visual basic the have a way they do it and maybe it's possible to change the code to work in vb.